# Selecting only one json object in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and currently working on interactive bubble chart and modifying to my need.The bubble chart I am working on is the below

http://sunsp.net/demo/BubbleMenu/

Source code and json file

http://sunsp.net/code/bubbleMenu.html

http://sunsp.net/code/main_bubble_json.html

In this code, I wish to select only 2 bubble by name.Say Atlas and Aglab and display only those two instead of all 4. How can I do that?

I tried the below to select one at a time ,but dint work.

```
        var bubbleObj = svg.selectAll(".topBubble")
                .data(root.children[0])
            .enter().append("g")
                .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "topBubbleAndText_" + i});

        console.log(bubbleObj);//bubble obj is null


       // nTop = root.children.length;
       nTop = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter a selection to specific items, use the [`selection.filter(selector)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) method:

```
var desiredNames = ["Atlas", "Aglab"];
var itemsWithDesiredNames = selection.filter(function(d, i) {
    return desiredNames.includes(d.name);
});
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use this with JSon.. because I not able to fit this in my code anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I can't, you should struggle with it a bit and see if you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

For each item, set its style visibility attribute to `visible` or `hidden` based on its name. Here is an example:

```
    .style("visibility", function(d) {
        return ["Atlas", "Aglab"].includes(d.name) ? "visible" : "hidden"
    })
```

To put it all together:

```
    // existing code to draw bubbles
    bubbleObj.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "topBubble")
        .attr("id", function(d,i) {return "topBubble" + i;})
        .attr("r", function(d) { return oR; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {return oR*(3*(1+i)-1);})
        .attr("cy", (h+oR)/3)
        .style("fill", function(d,i) { return colVals(i); })

        // set bubble visibility based on name of data item
        .style("visibility", function(d) {
            return ["Atlas", "Aglab"].includes(d.name) ? "visible" : "hidden"
        })
```

Comment: Thanks , But unfortunately this only changes visibility.
If I have 100 bubbles objects in my json file..all bubble will be present but only in visible.. This makes size of each bubble smaller.

Comment: See my second answer on how to narrow a selection using selection.filter()