# Selecting only a subset in d3.select

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am somewhat new to d3.js (and javascript in general). I am currently working on a tree similar to the one found in http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7926762. I am looking to add some filtering to not include certain nodes. I don't want to hide them, I want them not to be in the tree at all (as not to mess up spacing and such). The two parts I think are relevant for selecting only certain nodes from the json file are:

```
// define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", viewerWidth)
    .attr("height", viewerHeight)
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .call(zoomListener);
```

and maybe

```
// Updating nodes
    var node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });
```

There is a similar question in [Selecting only one json object in D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109154/selecting-only-one-json-object-in-d3), but I don't really understand how to use that answer.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to filter the JSON *before* you draw the tree, or really invoke any D3 code at all. In which case you can use javascript to filter the `treeData` list returned by `d3.JSON`. Does that sound like what you want to do?

Comment: @LondonRob Hi there, thanks for replying. Oh I hadn't even thought of that, it is exactly what I want to do... so I guess that would be just before `treeJSON = d3.json("vulnerabilities.json", function(error, treeData) {` then... I'll try it!

Comment: After! The open curly bracket starts a function in which the JSON has loaded and `treeData` is available. Before that line, the JSON hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: @LondonRob Oh yeah that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to remove some of the data from the tree is to remove it from the Array of data before you do anything with it in d3.

This means adding some filtering code at the point I've indicated below:

```
// Get JSON data
treeJSON = d3.json("manyNodes.json", function(error, treeData) {

    // treeData is available here! Add filtering code...
    // ...

    // Calculate total nodes, max label length
    var totalNodes = 0;
```

There are many ways to filter an Array in Javascript, which are nothing to do with d3 so kind of out of the scope of this question, but here's an example to get you started:

Assume your JSON has returned an Array like this:

```
var treeData = [{name:'a', age:10}, {name:'b', age:20},
    {name:'c', age:30}, {name:'d', age:40}]
```

You can then use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as follows:

```
> treeData.filter(function(d) { return d.age > 20; })
```

[image: Array filtering]

Comment: What a great answer! Thank you for the newbie friendly format! Regards/ David